# tensorflow conditional on axis

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am attempting to gather the indices of specific tensors/(vectors/matrices) within a tensor in keras.  Therefore, I attempted to use `tf.gather` with `tf.where` to get the indices to use in the gather function.

However, `tf.where` provides element wise indices for the matching values when testing for equality.  I would like to have the ability to find the indices (rows) for tensors (vectors) which are equal to another.

This is especially useful for finding the one-hot vectors within a tensor which match a set of one-hot vectors of interest.

I have some code to illustrate the shortcoming so far:

```
# standard 
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
sess = tf.Session()

# one-hot vector encoding labels
l = LabelBinarizer()
l.fit(['a','b','c'])

# input tensor 
t = tf.constant(l.transform(['a','a','c','b', 'a']))

# find the indices where 'c' is label
# ***THIS WORKS***
np.all(t.eval(session = sess) == l.transform(['c']), axis = 1)

# We need to do everything in tensorflow and then wrap in Lambda layer for keras so...
from keras import backend as K
# ***THIS DOES NOT WORK***
K.all(t.eval(session = sess) == l.transform(['c']), axis = 1)

# go on from here to get smaller subset of vectors from another tensor with the indicies given by `tf.gather`
```

Clearly the code above shows I have tried to get this conditional by axis to work, and it does fine in numpy, but the tensorflow version is not as easily ported from numpy.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to what you do, we can use `tf.reduce_all` which is the tensorflow equivalent of `np.all`:

```
tf.reduce_all(t.eval(session = sess) == l.transform(['c']), axis = 1)
```